# Mongos Vs Mongod Compatibility Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I run a Sharded Mongo Database in Production Environment.

Recently, once of the colleagues deprecated one of the Mongos (Router) instance and the new instance was spawned up (via ASG) with a latest minor version of Mongo 4.2 which is 4.2.14. Rest of the instances (shards, mongos and configs) continue to be on 4.2.5.

Soon after this, I am facing a problem to which I can find absolutely no documentation over the web. The problem happens only for the node which has the latest version of mongos - 4.2.14.

```
Error - Command failed with error 40415 (Location40415): 'BSON field '$mergeCursors.recordRemoteOpWaitTime' is an unknown field.' on server 10.17.9.84:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "BSON field '$mergeCursors.recordRemoteOpWaitTime' is an unknown field.", "code": 40415, "codeName": "Location40415", "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1620920773, "i": 1}}, "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1620920773, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash":

{"$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type": "00"}
, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "0"}}}}
```

After a day of digging into this I could understand that from any version 4.2.5 (unknown to us at the moment) onwards all requests going out of mongos have **recordRemoteOpWaitTime: true**. Since rest of the nodes are lower than *4.2.13*, they aren't able to recognise this attribute hence erroring out.

I cannot find any reference to this over the available documentation. I need to figure out a way to disable mongos passing this attribute to shards. Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: Is shutting down that one node a usable workaround?  If not, you'll probably need to downgrade.

Comment: Not really! The reason we have a Auto Scaling Groups (ASG) attached to it and the moment we kill the node, another node of a similar kind spawns up. If we change the ASG Script, it by default terminates the existing instances which would mean loss of data of around 2 TB.

Comment: I am eager to understand if there is a way to override this behaviour? To ensure this attribute is passed at all from the mongos to the shards. I tried bringing down the Compatibility Level to 4.0 but to no good cause. 
I am also looking at ways to de-associate ASG and then try making changes.

Comment: Why do you not upgrade the entire cluster to latest version?

Comment: Any upgrades of this nature would require substantial testing effort. Its a production system taking live traffic. Needless to mention the changes which might be required to some legacy bits of code.